# How much could/what would the average human be able to lift/carry if they were in a world where they are equivalently 1 inch tall?

Tags: humans, alternate-reality, strength

So I have this semi-old story concept where people are somehow teleported via a mysterious portal(I might change it to a door) to this dimension where everything is 72 times bigger and the day/night cycle are 72 times as long(could change) and organisms seem to live 72 times long as well. The tech-level and environment is pretty much that of our world.This means that humans from our Earth in this realm are pretty much insects as they are equivalently 1 inch and live kinda around as long as some insects live in that world.The square-cube law would not give them super strength or impact them negatively here or  anything.

So how much weight and/or what would the average human be able to lift/carry in this world?

Comment: "The square-cube law would not give them super strength or impact them negatively here". True, but conversely, everything from this scaled-up realm *would* suffer from the square-cube. Either you handwave the scaled-up natives so they're even remotely functional, or normal humans are *comparatively* very impressive

Comment: ? that is like if a tiny person from another visited our realm and said the same thing. This is because denizens of this scaled up are of 'normal' size in that realm. You do not see an elephant and go "but muh square-cube law".@Punintended

Comment: @ConanHighwoods ... no what they're saying is that not only would a human a quarter mile tall (= 72 times larger) be unable to move on earth because of the square-cube law, they would *literally* fall apart under their own body weight. hence why elephants are the largest land animals, because they have basically reached the limit of the square-cube law. much larger and they are simply not mobile enough to... idk, find food or something

Comment: I understand, but this realm is not Earth as we know. Just think of it as the law it their dimension scaling up for them, and somehow the portal gives Earth humans immunity from the negative effects of square-cube law.@

Comment: Plus they are not a 1/4 of a mile, more like 1/10, give or take a bit.@somebody

Answer (score 4):

If the teleported humans are not scaled up but stay the same size as they had on earth, they would be able to lift/carry the same load they were able to lift/carry on earth.

Their muscles aren't changed, their bones aren't changed, their proportions and absolute dimensions aren't changed.

Comment: But what would that equate to? a sand grain? A grain of rice? A jellybean?

Comment: @ConanHighwoods well... the answer to "how much" *is* "the same amount as on earth". the answer to "what" is... think of something humans can normally carry and scale it down 72 times. as for relative weight... no extra strength means humans can lift 72 * 72 * 72 = 373,000 times less of a big thing than they can of a small thing. assuming a human can lift their body weight, and their body weight is 111kg (~245lb) they can carry something that normally weighs 1.5g (~1/20oz)

Answer (score 2):

If everything is 72 times bigger, it kind of suggests the gravity is 373 times lower (assuming you mean linear size). Thus an unaltered human can lift about 373 times as much as here.

Comment: if in a normal situation one could lift 100 N, why would a lower gravity allow them to lift more?

Comment: @L.Dutch Earth-like gravity muscles vs objects affected by a gravity less than earth's would make that they can lift more mass(due to it being pulled down by gravity less) but not more weight(at the end of the day they'd still only be able to lift what feels like X amount of kilograms but what feels like a 20kg here is different to what feels like 20kg there)... if I remember the distinctions between mass and weight correctly.

Comment: @L.Dutch they would lift those 100N (±second order effects stemming from the same inertia, less friction, difficulties with grasping big objects etc.) but while on Earth 100N can lift 10.2kg, in this world  it would lift 3800 kg.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík the OP is asking "how much weight", not "how much mass" can they lift